# Borel Probability Measures on Compact Metric Space Are relatively Regular Closed

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology, probability-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and identify the set $P(X)$ of Borel probabilities measures with a convex subset $K_X$ of $C(X)'$ equipped with the weak$^{\star}$ topology.

Does $K_X$ satsify: $relcl(relint(K_X))=K_X$?  (Where $relint(K_X)$ is its relative interior on $P(X)$ and $relcl$ is its relative closure)?

Comment: Do you consider absolute or relative interior? Because $K_X$ is contained in an affine proper subspace of $C(X)’$ so has empty interior.

Comment: I can consider the relative interior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affine subspace spanned by $K_X$ is $\{f \in C(X)’,\, f(1)=1\}$ (use the measure characterization of $C(X)’$).

Let $\mu$ be in the relative interior of $K_X$. This means that for all $p \in C(X)’$ with $p(X)=1$, there exists arbitrarily small $0 < \lambda < 1$ such that $(1+\lambda)\mu-\lambda p$ and $(1-\lambda)\mu + \lambda p$ are probability measures. (*)

In particular, for all $p \in C(X)’$, $p(1)=1$, $A \subset X$, if $\mu(A)=0$, then $p(A)=0$. 
Therefore, every point of $X$ is an atom for $\mu$, hence $X$ is countable.

So if $X$ is uncountable, the relative interior of $K_X$ is empty.

Assuming now $X$ to be countable, (*) yields that for all $p \in C(X)’$, if $p(X)=1$ then $dp=fd\mu$ for some bounded function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So the same property holds if $p(X) \neq 0$ (scaling), thus for any $p$ (if $p(X)=0$ consider $p+\mu$).

This cannot hold if $X$ is infinite, regardless of topology.

So $K_X$ has nonempty relative interior iff $X$ finite iff it is regular.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding.  By relative interior, I mean the interior with respect to the subspace topology in $K_X$ not the relative interior of a convex set.

Comment: With the subspace topology, $K_X$ is both open and closed, isn’t it?

Comment: My mistake, my confusion was ridiculous.   But from this it seems we can't deduce that a dense subset of $C(X)'$ is dense in $K_X$ (with its relative topology)...